# Step from $\Big(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\Big)t$ to $\Big(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}\Big)t$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, chain-rule, change-of-variable

From this page between (2) and (3): https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m23s06/public_html/handouts/euler_eqns.pdf

$$\Big(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\Big)t=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}t$$

I always had difficulties with the chain rule, especially in Leibniz notation.

Where does the second derivative with respect to $t$ come from?

---

PDF transcribed with color for emphasis

> $$\begin{align}  \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} &=  \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx}\\
>  &=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt} t\right)\\
>  &=\color{red}{\left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)t}+\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}\\
>  &=\color{red}{\frac{d^2
>  y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}t}+\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}\\ &=\frac{d^2
>  y}{dt^2}t^2+\frac{dy}{dt}t \end{align}$$ Where we have again used the
>    fact that $dx/dt = t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that they (somewhat perversely) have $t$ as a function of $x$. Then the above is really the chain rule: To differentiate $\frac{dy}{dt}$ with respect to $x$, we must first differentiate with respect to $t$ and then $t$ by $x$ to uncover the rate of change in $x$. By the chain rule, these are multiplied
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it'd help to view it as the below operator acting on $y$. Note that the $t$ at the end in your expression in the LHS and RHS is a just a multiplicative factor and not acted upon by the operator.$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\right)= \left(\frac{\mathrm{d }t}{\mathrm{d} x} \right)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\right) = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d }t}{\mathrm{d} x} \right)\frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d} t^2}$$